# Modify BIOS settings from Windows

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, pxe

**Background**

I have several identical PC systems in the field, which are running Windows 10.
I can access them via RDP, but not physically (No Keyboard, Mouse, Display, etc.)

It's necessary now to perform a network boot (PXE) in order to install an OS update.

**Issue**

The UEFI BIOS is set to the Windows Bootmanager as first boot option. Also, the network stack is disabled.
In order to boot from my PXE Server, i need to change the above settings in the BIOS. As i mentioned, there is no physical access to the system.

The PC systems are using AMI BIOS, so i downloaded AFUWIN (It's a Windows x64 Utility, which allows to read/write the BIOS ROM)

My idea is to create a BIOS version, where PXE boot is enabled and set to #1 boot order.
Then, i will flash it from windows into the ROM of the PC.

Basically, it works. I can read the BIOS ROM and also write it. But somehow, it seems that the old boot settings are kept.

Are the settings stored somewhere outside the BIOS? I found out, that the user specific data is kept in the NVRAM section. I also tried to flash the NVRAM from AFUWIN, but it seems to be not working in the end.

TL;DR: I want to modify BIOS Settings using Windows. I have no physical access to the PC system. I created a custom BIOS and captured it using a BIOS manufacturer tool. I can also  successfully flash it onto the the target machine. The BIOS seems to be still the previous one. Is there any additional "reset NVRAM, CMOS, etc" command necessary?

Comment: To change configurable settings like boot order, you probably want something like AMIBCP

Comment: Maybe [BMT](https://github.com/ADLINK/bios-utility) could help.